# Error with operator< overload, invalid operands

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

When I try to use code like this:

```
namespace
{
    typedef boost::shared_ptr< float >  sharedFloat;
}

static bool operator<( const sharedFloat& inOne, float inTwo )
{
    return *inOne < inTwo;
}

static void foo()
{
    std::vector< sharedFloat > theVec;
    std::vector< sharedFloat >::iterator i =
        std::lower_bound( theVec.begin(), theVec.end(), 3.4f );
}
```

I get an error:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('boost::shared_ptr<float>' and 'float')
```

(with a pointer to the < comparison in the implementation of `lower_bound`.)  So, why are they invalid, when I provided an `operator<` with those operands?

If I instead use a comparison functor,

```
namespace
{
    typedef boost::shared_ptr< float >  sharedFloat;

    struct Comp
    {
        bool operator()( const sharedFloat& inOne, float inTwo )
        {
            return *inOne < inTwo;
        }
    };
}

static void foo()
{
    std::vector< sharedFloat > theVec;
    std::vector< sharedFloat >::iterator i =
        std::lower_bound( theVec.begin(), theVec.end(), 3.4f, Comp() );
}
```

then it compiles.  I could just do things that way, but I'd like to know why the first attempt failed.

**Added after solution:**  [Namespaces & Interface Principle](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill08.htm) by Herb Sutter helped clarify this stuff for me more.

Comment: does it work if you take the typedef out of the namespace?

Comment: @EHuhtala, no, that has no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call to `operator <` is performed inside the `std` namespace. The compiler will therefore look for appropriate overloads of `operator <` in the `std` namespace and in the namespace of its arguments (ADL). If one operator is found (*even if it is not viable*!), enclosing namespaces are **not** searched.

Since your `operator <` is defined in the global namespace, the compiler will not consider it (since another overload `operator <` exists in the `std` namespace and is found before name look up may consider enclosing namespaces).

Finally, since `std::operator <` is not viable, the compiler will emit an error.

When passing your own functor as the last argument, things are obviously different: instead of looking for a viable `operator <`, the argument itself is invoked, and everything compiles fine.

Comment: Why doesn't the `float` argument count as being in the global namespace?

Comment: @JWWalker: `float` is a built-in type of the language, it is not defined in any namespace. To get convinced, try doing `::float x = 0;`, you will see the compiler gives you an error.

Answer (score 4):

Your `operator<` will not be found by `lower_bound`, because it is not in any namespace associated with the types you use.

The compiler will look in namespaces `std` and `boost`, but not in the global namespace because nothing involved comes from there.

When you pass `Comp` explicilty it works, because then the compiler doesn't have to search for a matching operator.